# find a number after a special character and multiply it by awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, text

I have a file:

```
"UDP", "x", 12880, "any", "any", x, 0.0.0.0/0, 0.0.0.0/0, {85000, drop, -1, fast+dsample:1000}, {1m, alert, -1, none}
```

How can I change 85000 number which is after "{" and multiply it by a value to reduce it by awk.
like: 85000*0.75= 63,750
Final line should be:

```
"UDP", "x", 12880, "any", "any", x, 0.0.0.0/0, 0.0.0.0/0, {63750, drop, -1, fast+dsample:1000}, {1m, alert, -1, none}
```

Comment: Just that once, or on multiple lines? Just `{85000` or `'{[0-9]+'`?

Comment: I  want to use it in a bash script that change the given line. so just for a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With any awk (for example, mawk):

```
mawk 'match($0,/{[0-9]+/) {
  d = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH)
  $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART) 0.75*d substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
} 1' file
"UDP", "x", 12880, "any", "any", x, 0.0.0.0/0, 0.0.0.0/0, {63750, drop, -1, fast+dsample:1000}, {1m, alert, -1, none}
```

With GNU awk:

```
gawk 'match($0,/([^{]*{)([0-9]+)(.*)/,a){$0 = a[1] 0.75*a[2] a[3]} 1' file
"UDP", "x", 12880, "any", "any", x, 0.0.0.0/0, 0.0.0.0/0, {63750, drop, -1, fast+dsample:1000}, {1m, alert, -1, none}
```

---

Alternatively, with perl

```
perl -pe 's/(?<={)\d+/0.75 * $&/e' file
"UDP", "x", 12880, "any", "any", x, 0.0.0.0/0, 0.0.0.0/0, {63750, drop, -1, fast+dsample:1000}, {1m, alert, -1, none}
```